# Duplicate cells being exported as one cell

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to export a simple spreadsheet where some of the cells are empty and some are full.

Every time this XSL exporter reads a cell which is the same as the cell before it doesn't write it. If there are cells with identical values next to each other they are missed out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
   xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
   xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
   exclude-result-prefixes="office table text">

<xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes" encoding = "UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration = "yes"/>


<xsl:param name="targetURL"/>

<!-- Process the document model -->
<xsl:template match="/">

<data name="SiteData"><xsl:apply-templates select="//table:table"/></data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table:table">
  <!-- Process all table-rows after the column labels in table-row 1 -->
  <xsl:for-each select="table:table-row">
     <!-- Process the  columns -->
        <xsl:for-each select="table:table-cell">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>:</xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:value-of select="text:p"/> ;</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried every possible solution but I just can't work this out. Does anybody have an idea how to write ':' for every cell regardless of if it is empty or duplicated

Comment: I suspect the source XML that you are working from omits the duplicate cells, perhaps it includes some kind of repeat count to say "this cell is repeated N times". Find a simple example that demonstrates the problem and look carefully at the XML representation.

Comment: I've made an import filter which successfully writes the spreadsheet, including duplicate and empty cells. The problem is when the export filter above tries to save this spreadsheet into the XML form, it doesn't write the cells if they are repeated in the same row.